# How can I compare different values with same ids of different dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two different DataFrame named df1 and df2, with same id column, but some ids have the same count and some ids have the different counts, so I want to get the data for same ids with the different count values, and both DataFrames have the different indexes

following is my df1

```
    id  valueA
0   255 1141
1   91  1130
2   347 830
3   30  757
4   68  736
5   159 715
6   32  713
7   110 683
8   225 638
9   257 616
```

my df2 is

```
    id  valueB
0   255 1231
1   91  1170
2   5247  954
3   347 870
4   30  757
5   68  736
6   159 734
7   32  713
8   110 683
9   225 644
10  257 616
11  917 585
12  211 575
13  25  530
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge` and filter dataframe with `query`:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='id').query('valueA != valueB')
```

Output:

```
    id  valueA  valueB
0  255    1141    1231
1   91    1130    1170
2  347     830     870
5  159     715     734
8  225     638     644
```

Same method different syntax:

```
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on='id')
df_out[df_out['valueA'] != df_out['valueB']]
```

In response to commment below:

Sure you can use set_index and let pandas handle alignment.

```
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
df2 = df2.set_index('id')

df_diff = df1['valueA'] - df2['valueB']

df_diff = df_diff[df_diff.notnull() & df_diff.ne(0)]

pd.concat([df1.reindex(df_diff.index), df2.reindex(df_diff.index)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     valueA  valueB
id                 
91     1130    1170
159     715     734
225     638     644
255    1141    1231
347     830     870
```

Comment: I have see this many people have used merge function, why can't I do it without merging both DataFrames, 
and  thank you, query function is new for me.. i will read more about this function.

Comment: @id101112  Sure, you can use set_index and then filter both dataframes based on math operation and concat results.

Comment: `query` it somewhat of a shortcut, syntatic sugar.  It doesn't always work, when column names have spaces or special characters you cannot use `query`.  But, when you can use `query` it makes the code more readable.